# which gradle version is compatible with java 20

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, build.gradle, version

I am facing the issue in build.gradle file in android studio while using flutter

I tried to upgrade the version to java 20 but now this is also not compatible with the build version

Comment: None - you can check gradle java version compatibility here - [Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you try to use Java 20? Better use the JRE that is included in Android Studio.

Comment: Because java 20 is latest version I thought of all the features availability.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [Gradle compatibility](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) docs, Java 20 and up is not yet supported.

Comment: Which java version is supported then?

Comment: The link I shared tells you which supported versions there are. You need between 8 and 19 for Gradle but for specific versions, refer to the matrix in the link.

Answer (score 3):

8.1 can target Java 20, but not execute on Java 20. See the release notes here: https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/release-notes.html#jvm

8.2 will have full Java 20 support. See the related issue here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/23488

Comment: 8.1 works for me.